# Database support in GE Smallworld?

Tags: sql-server, oracle-dbms, smallworld-gis

What database engine can be used for GE Smallworld?

I have poor information but I read about Smallword proprietary VMDS.

Is it possible to use Oracle or SQL Server?

Comment: From Google it looks like Oracle may be supported.

Comment: Yes, I tried to find it on the Internet, but I am not sure so I would like the answer from someone who knows it.

Comment: Smallworld can definitely be connected to Oracle databases long years ago.

Answer (score 2):

Smallworld uses its own proprietary database system, but can connect to Oracle.

Comment: So if you are implementing Smallworld from scratch - could be Oracle used as the main database?

Comment: yes, we use smallworld with oracle spatial.

Comment: @Mapperz: So if I understand it well - Oracle can be used instead of VMDS? Or VMDS is implemented in Oracle?

Comment: https://www.gegridsolutions.com/geospatial/catalog/smallworld_gateway.htm but we are moving away from smallworld to a oracle (spatial) 12c r2 solution

Comment: And what is the reason of moving to Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

Yes oracle is supported as a database technology for Smallworld. You can implement these from scratch (and in fact, it might be better to do this).
There is a system administration overhead for using Oracle compared to VMDS and depending upon your site size, there may be performance differences.